# Beautiful Soup: Retrieving Item from HTML

Tags: html, beautifulsoup

I have the following source code:

```
<div class="search-results-listings-list__item-description__characteristics-popover">
    Bedrooms
</div>
    4
```

I want to retrieve the number of bedrooms, which is 4, but because of the `div` between Bedrooms and 4 I cannot, anyone have any ideas? This is my current code, which only gives me "Bedroom" as a result.

```
bedrooms=soup.find_all(class_="search-results-listings-list__item-description__characteristics-popover")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `next_sibling` to get the `4`

```
div=soup.find(class_="search-results-listings-list__item-description__characteristics-popover")
sibling=div.next_sibling
print(div.get_text()+sibling) 
#Bedrooms        4
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have also want to find all of the "siblings" in the page source, but I can't use find_all. I tried to use a loop but I don't get the right result. Here is my code:

for i in soup:
    div=soup.find(class_="search-results-listings-list__item-description__characteristics-popover")
    sibling=div.next_sibling
    print(sibling)